# how to use ngifelse correctly in angular9?

Tags: angular

I am having a list of posts which i am fetching using services and populating on the UI.There is a search box defined based on the id.My requirement is that when i provide the id and it is there,it should be rendered in a card.This is working fine.But the issue is that when i provide an id which is not there then it should give a message that user isnt found.
I am trying to use an ngifelse syntax for this.

my html page is :

```
<div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="ID" (keyup.enter)="onSearch($event)" class="form-control" id="txtSearchText" name="SearchText" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
            <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3" *ngIf="showcard; else elseblock">

                <div>{{searchPost.userId}}</div>
                <div>{{searchPost.id }}<div>
                <div>{{searchPost.title}}</div>
                <div>{{searchPost.body}}</div>
            </div>

            <ng-template  #elseBlock>User is not found try again</ng-template>                                  


        </div>
```

also the ts file is:

```
onSearch(event:any){
    this.searchText=event.target.value;

    this.projectService.searchUsers()
    .subscribe((response:Posts[])=>{   
      if(response[this.searchText-1]) {    
        var p: Posts = new Posts();
        this.searchPost.userId=response[this.searchText-1].userId;
        this.searchPost.id=response[this.searchText-1].id;
        this.searchPost.title=response[this.searchText-1].title;
        this.searchPost.body=response[this.searchText-1].body;
        this.showcard=true;
      }
      else
      { //this.showcard=false;
        console.log("user id not found")
        console.log(this.showcard)
      }   
      }
    )

  }
```

I have defined the properties as below in ts file.

```
showcard:boolean=false;

elseblock:TemplateRef<any>
```

the issue is when it isnt there ,it printing correctly on console but somehow the ngifelse is not working.Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement if-else in angular in the following way:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  checkValidity : boolean = false;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p *ngIf = "checkValidity; then ifBlock; else elseBlock"></p>


<ng-template #ifBlock>
  <p> If Block is rendered </p>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <p> Else Block is rendered </p>
</ng-template>
```

Hope it solves your query :)

Comment: this is working fine for me..but just one more thing the else part is being rendered by default once the page loads.I want it to load only when the userid entered is invalid.Can you pls help on that

Comment: Change the default value of the checkValidity flag to true @RIni

Comment: if i do so the div is rendered as it is with values displayed as 0 .I want it not to appear initially.when search is initiated,then it should appear as found or not found

Comment: Based on the userId valid status, updated the corresponding boolean value, that holds validity of user. Use the boolean value the render the IF Else block. So that block will be rendered every time the boolean value is changed